# State of research in productivity, work fatigue and workplace policies

Tags: io-psychology

I am interested in any kind of summary research that links workplace policies, productivity and fatigues. For example, if someone has worked 10 hours one day, will they be as productive the next day? Can workplace policies such as time-off-in-lieu remediate it?

There is a [related question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/24102/mental-fatigue-and-recovery-schedule), but it seems to be unanswered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot see how this question is different to your "related question". Can you clarify this point please?

Comment: I am looking at the workplace policy angle - how can a workplace enable knowledge workers to be productive by reducing fatigue so that most of the hours spent are productive.

Comment: OK, well as a pointer, when I was working on the railways with 24 hour rosters, there was a policy where a minimum of 12 hours was required between shifts and 36 hours minimum going from a night shift to a day shift. Whether that was as a result of research, I don't know.